# How to test controllers that has akka system injected for Play framework?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, playframework, controller

Below is my controller:

```
package controllers

import java.util.TimeZone

import akka.actor.{ActorNotFound, ActorSystem}
import akka.util.Timeout
import com.google.inject.Inject
import com.typesafe.akka.extension.quartz.QuartzSchedulerExtension
import play.api.Logger
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
import play.api.libs.json.{JsValue, JsError, JsSuccess}
import play.api.mvc._

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class ScheduleController @Inject()(system: ActorSystem) extends Controller {

  val scheduler = QuartzSchedulerExtension.get(system)
  implicit val timeout = new Timeout(5.seconds)

  def index = Action.async {
    Future.successful(Ok("hi"))
  }

  def run = Action.async { request =>
    // find actor and "start" it by sending message to it, return Ok() if found
    // if actor is not found, return BadRequest()
    // if error return InternalServerError()
  }
}
```

I've been looking for tutorials but most are outdated since they deal with Play 2.3.

Comment: I think Plays documentation is very detailed here. For testing actors you can use akka-testkit. http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/testing.html

Comment: im following the documentation and nothings to be working for me.. even pointing to diff config when on test doesnt work... javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.file=test/scala/conf/application-test.conf"

Comment: What testing framework(ScalaTest or Specs2) do you use? Do you plan to write unit tests or integration tests? To override a config for a integration test you can follow this tutorial. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaTestingWithGuice#Configuration Here is a complete example which tests a controller with the help of the GuiceApplicationBuilder https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette/blob/master/silhouette-testkit/test/com/mohiva/play/silhouette/test/FakesSpec.scala#L249

Answer (score 0):

I solved a very similar problem with Play2 controllers and actors except in my case I'm not injecting an `ActorSystem` into my controller. Rather, I use Play's default actor system and create actors from my global settings object when my application starts. For a given actor I provide a selection method in its companion object. For example:

```
class MyActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Request => sender ! Response
  }
}

object MyActor {
  val path = // assuming fixed actor path
  val sys  = // reference to play actor system
  def select: ActorSelection = sys.actorSelection(path)

  // my actor messages
  case object Request
  case object Response
}
```

The way I have this actor setup I plan on asking it from inside my controller method using a `Request` and expect to process a `Response` object back from it. The controller is a non-actor `sender` in this scenario. By calling `ask` on the actor selection, I close over the future and map the result to a partial function that matches the expected response. Here's what my controller looks like:

```
class MyController extends Controller {

  implicit val timeout = // set your timeout duration

  def index = Action.async {
    MyActor.select ? Request map {
      case Response => Ok("success")
    }
  }
}
```

Testing this controller endpoint is *VERY* challenging because your actor might not be in a ready state to start handling messages. I spent about two days trying to figure out how to properly block on the my actor's lifecycle state using the actor selection I've exposed through its companion object. What I ended up doing inside my test class that worked for me was to create a method that takes in a function parameter and loops over my actor state until I can resolve its `ActorRef`. I'm a fan of `ScalaTest` so this is what my unit tests amounted to:

```
class MySpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers with BeforeAndAfterAll {

  implicit val fakeApp: FakeApplication = new FakeApplication()
  override def beforeAll() = Play.start(fakeApp)
  override def afterAll() = Play.stop(fakeApp)

  def awaitableActorTest(assertions: => Any): Unit = {
    val timeout = 1.second
    var isActorReady = false
    while(!isActorReady) {
      val futureRef = Await.ready(MyActor.select.resolveOne(timeout), timeout)
      futureRef.value.get match {
        case Success(_) =>
          assertions
          isActorReady = true
        case Failure(_) =>
          Thread.sleep(2000)
      }
    }
  }

  it should "process actor request and response via controller endpoint" in {
    awaitableActorTest {
      val result = route(routes.MyController.index).get
      status(result) shouldBe OK
      contentAsString(result) shouldBe "success"
    }
  }

}
```

What I get out of this `awaitableActorTest` pattern is a really clean way of reliably hitting my controller endpoint only when my actor is alive and available to process messages. If it's not, my `ActorRef` using its selection companion won't resolve in the future with success -- instead it completes with failure. When it fails I sleep a few seconds and repeat the loop. I break the loop when I its selection successfully resolved an `ActorRef`.

I'm unfamiliar with the `QuartzSchedulerExtension` to which you refer in your code snippet, but I hope my example is useful.